# Coldfusion, outputting SQL results grouped by Date Grouping, Today, Yesterday, This Week, etc

Tags: sql, mysql, datetime, coldfusion, grouping

I'm hitting the DB for a 100 records from a MySQL DB that have a DateAdded (timestamp) column.

I'd like to find a SMART way to display the records as follows in Coldfusion, w/o hitting the database multiple times.

Today:
- records.....
Yesterday:
- records.....
Earlier This Week:
- records.....
Earlier This Month:
- records.....
Older:
- records.....

Thanks for the ideas on how to get this done smartly in ColdFusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query of Queries? - http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/using_recordsets_3.html#1157970

```
<h1>Today:</h1>
<cfquery name="todayRecords" dbtype="query">
    select *
    from originalQuery
    where DateAdded = #createODBCDate(year(now()), month(now()), day(now()))#
</CFQUERY>
<cfdump var="#todayRecords#">
```

You may want to use the `BETWEEN` SQL operator. See: http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/using_recordsets_7.html

You may also use `<cfqueryparam>` tag. See: http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/Tags_p-q_18.html#1102474

Query of Queries might not be the most efficient, but in my opinion it is the cleanest way to represent your intent and it just works.

Comment: If the column really is a timestamp, and contains both a date and time, then a straight equality comparison will not work. Either a range check (or truncating the time) would be needed

WHERE  DateAdded <= #TodayAtMidnight# AND DateAdded < #TomorrowAtMidnight#

Comment: The edit function does not seem to be working. Correction: 
WHERE  DateAdded >= #TodayAtMidnight# AND DateAdded < #TomorrowAtMidnight#

Comment: @Leigh, yes, and you may use BETWEEN

Comment: @Henry - Yes, it can be done with BETWEEN. But it is easier to use >= and < IMO. Since BETWEEN is _inclusive_, it will include a little more information than is desired (if not constructed correctly).

Answer (score 1):

multiple db calls would have a pretty negligible cost in most apps

but, this can all be done in one call, if you selet all the records and order by time desc.

end the current section when the time switches (when it becomes older than 1 day, older than 2 days, older than 8 days, etc)

basically you would use [DateCompare](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/6.1/htmldocs/functi56.htm) function in CF to compare DateAdd to that section's cut-off point. some pseudocode:

## today

while dateadd < tomorrow
   print record

## yesterday

while dateadd < 1 week ago
  print record

## earlier this week

while dateadd < 1 month ago
  print record

Comment: How can I make the switch in Coldfusion elegantly?

Comment: You could make the "switch" by keeping a variable that keeps track of the section you are on.  When that section no longer matches the "LastSection", create the next header.

Comment: Neil can you provide an example in CF that shows how that looping would work?

Answer (score 1):

you'd have to start on the SQL Side, either a Store Procedure or a User Defined function to add the Today/Yesterday/etc label to each record.

Perhaps:

```
Select a, b, myFunction(DateColumn) as GroupLabel 
From myTable Order By GroupLabel
```

Where myFunction takes the date value and returns Today/Yesterday/etc

Comment: This is a great approach, and will also work for any ad-hoc reports designed directly against the database.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Neil.  If it were me I would do it all in a Stored Proc and just let the DB hand CF the final results for output.